# How to get order by last name if single field "name" contains both first name and last name

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

I have a database field "name" that contains both first name and last name of the user. 
For Example:

```
id  name
1   Martha Ron
2   Ryan Knapp
3   John Mithchell
4   Scott Mathews
5   Dean Johns
.....
.....
```

How can i get all users order by last name?

**Note:** I can not create a another field in the database as it is a production database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)

```
SELECT
* FROM `table`
ORDER BY 
 SUBSTRING_INDEX(`name`, ' ', -1);
```

### [See fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6fe8ee/1)

Comment: What about "Tjeerd Jan van der Molen" :)

Comment: @AzizShaikh there is no optimal guess to find the right space to distinguish the first and last name according to sample data the word after last space is assumed to be the last name

Answer (score 2):

Try this ... ref http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

```
SELECT *, SUBSTRING_INDEX(`name`, ' ', -1) as sortname 
from tablename order sortname;
```

Comment: And hope that `name` consists of First name and last name only (there can be middle names in there too).